# Installing mongodb on 64bit machines

Tags: mongodb, 64-bit, windows-10

My question is pretty simple :
How to install Mongodb for a 64 bit windows 10 machine.
I have no clue as to what version of mongodb is available now on the website, but I believe it's downloading the 32 bit version.
There is a tab called Compass which has the option of downloading a windows 7-64 bit version, but whats the difference between Community server and compass.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the directions from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/).

When you download, you want the "Community Server". Compass is a separate visualization and query tool.